# CakePHP admin section routing and redirecting

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm struggling with the concept of creating an admin section in CakePHP-project. (version 2.3.5)

I have uncommented the line in Config/core.php:

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

I have added the line in Config/routes.php: (Just as they advice to do in CakePHP cookbook.)

```
Router::connect('/admin', array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'index','admin' => true));
```

In AppController.php I have the following:

```
    public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'index', 'admin'=>true),
        'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'display','home'),
        'authError'=>'you have no access.',
        'authorize'=>array('Controller')
    )
);
```

Then I have added a layout View/Pages/admin_index.ctp which is where I want to be redirected after login. I managed to get my login working in UsersController.php.

So the question is, where should I redirect in AppController.php to get my logged admin to the admin_view? I believe that loginRedirect is somehow broken..

I have studied some tutorials on this subject but I have found only this Youtube-video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvwQGZ1BxdM All other tutorials seem to be concerning earlier versions of CakePHP.

Comment: Are you using an ACL? Because in that case, are you sure you added it to the ACO's list? I have had a same sort of problem where it wouldn't redirect because I simply forgot to update my ACO's *facepalm*. If that's not the case: do you get redirected at all? What happens when you make it redirect to a non-admin page?

Comment: No, I'm not using ACL.. too confusing for me.

Comment: No, not using ACL. I managed to get it working somehow, but I don't know is it a good practice or just plain luck.. I changed this: 'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'display','home', 'admin'=>false) AND isAuthorized() if($this->Auth->user('role') == 'admin') returns true. After login it redirects to /admin but in admin_logout it redirects to /users/login It would be more simple if logout would redirect just to '/' This is messy..

Comment: Ah, that's because it is remembering the prefix probably. I have this issue all the time when creating anchor tags. It seems to set the prefix to true automatically once you are "on that prefix". That's why I extend my HtmlHelper that automatically sets all the prefixes to false unless I tell it to set it to true. That might be causing your problems. Does that sound like your problem? If not, we have to search further :)

Comment: I tried setting prefixes false with no luck. But I got it working more or less. I get back to it later. Thanks for your help! Another thing occurred.. after logout it redirects outside of that admin panel, but when I press previous from browser toolbar it goes straight inside to my admin panel. Shouldn't Auth->logout() destroy session data? I have beforeFilter in AppController that allows 'index'. Is it possible that it uses admin_-prefix on that method? I use a layout called admin_index.ctp on my admin page.

Comment: It should destroy session data, yes. But your browser caches the views when pressing "back" to prevent unnecessary page loads. You can check this by simply printing a `date('H:i:s');` to the screen and check if it is on the same time when you press back. If so, the page is cached ;) So it won't be a security breach, because the page won't be updated. Since the controller will need an authorised user for that. Try f5'ing. You will notice it won't work.

Comment: But, you said "I got it working more or less". Feel free to update your question (make clear what the updates are and don't remove the old content so we can iterate on that). Ping me when you updated the question. Otherwise I won't notice ;)

Comment: You were right. It destroyed the session data and the admin_index was just browser-cached. In other words, if I try to push links on admin_index to other admin-related actions, it redirects to login-view. So it works perfectly. Big thanks @Jelmer !

Comment: Anyone care to write an accepted answer to this? Don't forget about the Controller::disableCache(); method (before you start chasing ways to do it manually). This got me stuck quite a few times.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could set a loginAction in AppController and then inside this action you could do:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'someController','action'=>'someAction','admin'=>true));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'autoRedirect' => false,
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'admin' => true,
            'controller' => 'dashboard',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),

        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login',
            'admin' => false,
            'plugin' => false,
        ),
    ),
);
    // Now the before Filter which tells it its okay to go to index/view/or display actions.
    public function beforeFilter() {    
    // Allow public views
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view', 'display');
    }
```

for the user login you'd do something like this:

```
    public function login() {
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'User Sign In');
     if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Username or password is incorrect', 'flash_bad');
        }
    }
}
```

any methods you want to access you'd do public function admin_index, admin_view admin_settings, etc. so that in the controller of widgets the route would be /admin/widgets/index /admin/widgets/index and so forth and so on.  The trick to allowing other pages to be rendered without auth is just putting the $this->Auth->allow in the beforeFilter.

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution. Admin panel for website has another graphics, javasctipt etc, so I do in my app folders:

```
app_name
  +Model
  +Plugin
  +admin
  +front
```

Yes admin is in another folder, so I can for example set another cookie to login in admin area only plugins and model are the same. This folder structure needs some configuration in bootstrap.php:

```
  App::build(array(
      'Plugin' => array(ROOT . DS . 'Plugin' . DS),
      'Model' => array(ROOT . DS . 'Model' . DS),
      'Model/Behavior' => array(ROOT . DS . 'Model' . DS . 'Behavior' . DS),
  ));
```

Maybe is crazy for you but i prefer this solution that use admin routes.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

**Your config/routes.php**

`Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard' ));`

**Appcontroller**

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array(
    'Acl',
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array( 
                'userModel' => 'User',
                 'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'user_name',
                    'password' => 'password'
                    )
                )
            ),
        'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
                    'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'mysettings'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
        'authError' => 'You don\'t have access here.',
                /*
                'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'forgot_password'),
                'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'),
                'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'forgot_password'),
                'authError' => 'You don\'t have access here.',
                */
        ),

);
```

**Usercontroller**

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

/**
 * Components
 *
 * @var array
 */ 
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('login','logout');
}

}
```