# Does Cakephp Auth can be use even in other controller?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

Recently, I've been studying cake, I've seen the auth library which said to be will take care of the access control over your app, but, it seems like, you can't initialize or even use this auth library when you're not in the 'UsersController', i did not want that, what if it has some admin part wherein i want the URI to be admin/login, or just simply /login, i've been scratching my head over this one, please help.

Another question, why it seems like the functionality of the '$this->redirect' is not effective when i'm putting this one at any method that contains nothing but redirection, or even in the __construct()?

thanks guys, hoping someone could clearly explain to me those things.

Comment: the similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820195/cakephp-admin-section-routing-and-redirecting

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Auth component inside any controller in the application. If you want it will only effect with the admin section then you can add condition in the beforeFilter funciton in you application AppController on Auth initialization like.

```
// for component initialization.
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
         'authenticate' => array(
            'userModel' => 'Customer', // you can also specify the differnt model instead of user
        'Form' => array(
        'fields' => array('username' => 'email')        
         )
      )
    )
}
```

and you can bind this on the admin routing like

```
function beforeFilter(){        
    // only works with admin routing.
    if(isset($this->request->params['prefix']) && ($this->request->params['prefix'] == 'admin')){
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect  = array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => true);
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'customers', 'action' => 'login');
    }
}
```

If you're using cake 2.3.x or later then make sure you have specified the redirect action in correct format like.

```
return $this->redirect('action_name'); // you can also specify the array of parameters.
```